# Is it possible to prevent files on a usb drive from being searched on any computer?

Tags: filesystems, usb-storage, windows-search, file-search, hidden-file

I have searched, but all methods that I found need to be done on computers. I have a usb drive, and I may use it on different computers. It's impossible to set "Indexing Option" on every computer.

So, can I do something to this usb drive to make some files not being searched on any computer?

Comment: Encrypt the drive?

Comment: Are the “any computers” under your configuration control or do you want to prevent the search ability of the drive on a random computer which of course is impossible.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to prevent the search ability on a random computer.

Comment: do you want to prevent search, or prevent search indexing?

Comment: @FrankThomas I don't know the difference. When I search some keywords in the search bar, I don't want some files to appear in the result.

Comment: @Ryan - These random machines are under your Administrative control? Outside of using BitLocker anything you do to the drive I could reverse as an experienced Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound Honestly, I don't want people to know those files exist on the drive. That's why I don't want those files to appear in search result. I can hide them, but they will still show up when search.

Comment: @Ryan - If it’s my own machine I can just enable Search Indexing on the drive. You will have to just encrypt the drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I will try encryption, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use
[VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html)
to create a VeraCrypt volume on the disk that for other users will look
just like any file. You could even disguise the file as an unallocated
space on the disk, so it will be completely invisible.

You would need to *mount* this file in order to see it as a new disk
on the computer, that can be handled as any other external disk.

If you would like to use it on other computers, where VeraCrypt is not
installed, you could put the VeraCrypt software on the disk.

For more information, see the VeraCrypt documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would just do it matrix style.
RED pill, blue pill.
In this case RED usb drive, and blue USB drive.
The RED one you would ONLY plug into YOUR PC, and the BLUE one who cares.

I would just have 5 USB drives in my pocket so I have no excuse for needing to use the RED thumb anywhere.

You would have to encapsulate the files into another file.

Say a ZIP with or without encryption.
In windows you can create a VHD file which is a virtual hard drive, and put your files there.  Encrypted or not windows not automatically mount these files.

However, mounting it would show up a drive letter, and the content would be indexed after that.

The indexer would show whatever.vhd or whatever.zip or etc but that is it.
It would not go any deeper.

Most form of compression or encapsulation offer some form of encryption or password protection if you need to make sure the content isn't automatically mounted an indexed.

Answer (score -1):

Your question could be more clear on what you want, as it actually sounds confusing and producing answers like encrypting the drive, and I think we are mostly trying to answer after assuming. I believe you are actually asking how to **disable the Windows searching and indexing feature on an specific USB drive**. And when you say "It's impossible to set "Indexing Option" on every computer", I think you mean you need to modify the Windows 10 general Indexing preferences, right?.

Try this.

Right click on your USB drive (you can do the same on a folder too), and on general you will see "allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties", uncheck.  On a folder, you will see this option under the "Advanced" button. Check and see if this does what you need to achieve.

Comment: Anything you can do, other than encryption, can be reversed in other computers.